# Linq query is getting more records than sql query

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

I have a sql query which will give me around 30 record but the same query once I changed to linq query its giving me thousands of  record. I cant find the actual root cause of the problem can any one help me ...

sql query

```
            select 
DLId = p.Id,
TopicId = st.Id,
TopicName = at.Name,
PrimaryOrg = bo.BusinessUnit,
StatusId = ns.ID,
ModifiedBy = pa.LastName 

from  STopics st
join ATopics at on st.Id = at.Id
join Students p on st.StudentId = p.Id
join Sorgs sbu on at.BUorgID = sbu.BUOrgID
join BOrgs bo on sbu.BUOrgID = bo.ID
join Status ns on st.SID = ns.ID
 join Students pa on st.NominatedBy = pa.Email
where p.IsActive = 1 and sbu.StudentID = 123 and sbu.IsActive = 1
```

and the linq query is

```
(from st in Context.STopics 
join at in Context.ATopics  on st.Id equals at.Id
join p in Context.Students  on st.StudentId  equals p.Id 
join sbu in Context.Sorgs  on at.BUorgID equals sbu.BUOrgID  
join bo in Context.BOrgs  on sbu.BUOrgID equals bo.ID
join ns in Context.Status  on st.SID equals ns.ID
join pa in Context.Students  on st.NominatedBy equals pa.Email
where  p.IsActive==true && sbu.StudentID == 123 && sbu.IsActive == true
 select new result()
 {
 DLId = p.Id,
  TopicId = st.Id,
  TopicName = at.Name,
 PrimaryOrg = bo.BusinessUnit,
 StatusId = ns.ID,
 ModifiedBy  = pa.LastName
 })
```

Comment: StudentID <> ParticipantID

Comment: sry, that was a typo. corrected.

Comment: Check the [generated SQL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386961%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Checking the generated SQL will be the ideal case. Alternatively, rather than rely on implicit Boolean conversion, can you try changing your LINQ query to p.IsActive = 1 just like in your SQL query?

Answer (score 0):

```
(from st in Context.STopics 
join at in Context.ATopics  on st.Id equals at.Id
join p in Context.Students  on new { st.StudentId, p.IsActive }   equals new { p.Id , true}
join sbu in Context.Sorgs  on new { sbu.BUorgID, sbu.IsActive,sbu.StudentID }  equals new { at.BUorgID , true, 123}
join bo in Context.BOrgs  on sbu.BUOrgID equals bo.ID
join ns in Context.Status  on st.SID equals ns.ID
join pa in Context.Students  on st.NominatedBy equals pa.Email
select new result()
{
DLId = p.Id,
TopicId = st.Id,
TopicName = at.Name,
PrimaryOrg = bo.BusinessUnit,
StatusId = ns.ID,
ModifiedBy  = pa.LastName
})
```

Can you try this one, if you want to get exact issue, you can get how sql query is generated from the linq statements, linq query uses lots of inner query methodology

```
var query= your linqquery;
string sqlQuery=query.ToString();

you can review sqlQuery.
```